# SQL Server Group By Max Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to write the SQL Query. I have data like this:

[image]

I'd like to group by Venue Id and get a count for the Max Date. So I'd expect my result to look like:

[image]

Comment: So what *have* you tried so far, why didn't it work? What's wrong with the aptly named `MAX` and `COUNT` functions?

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `dense_rank()`:

```
select venue_id, date, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by venue_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by venue_id, date;
```

With a fun trick, you don't need a subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties venue_id, date, count(*)
from t
group by venue_id, date
order by row_number() over (partition by venue_id order by date desc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for ROW_NUMBER() with partition by.

```sql
SELECT VenueId, Date as MaxDate, ItemCount
from
(
SELECT VenueId, Date, ItemId, ItemCount, row_number() over(partition by venueId ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rnk 
from table) as t
WHERE rnk = 1
```